# I changed the status of my app to "In Production" in the google cloud console, do I need to generate OAuth 2.0 Client IDs again?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

I initially configured the app as testing and generated OAuth 2.0 Client ID. Due to this issue the refresh token was expiring every 7 days. I currently now changed the status of the app to "In Production", will I need to generate the OAuth 2.0 Client ID again so as to ensure that refresh token generated now is valid longer?

I generated the token.json file again using python after making configuration changes. But I am unable to check whether this refresh token is valid longer or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to generate a new refresh token. this refresh token will no longer expire.

Just delete the token.json file and your python app should request a new one.

Comment: Thank you Linda Lawton, No need to change any configuration in OAuth2.0 Client ID screen in the google cloud console right?

Comment: no as log as you clicked the button to set it into production your refresh tokens will stop expiring.